# When new features get added to Minecraft PE do they appear in existing worlds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

For example, when they added dungeons and fortresses, would those randomly generate in an existing world? I know things like the nether, where you have to take an action to enter, will work. But let's say they add undersea temples to PE in the future--would I have to start a new world to have a chance of finding one? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have almost no expertise in the pocket edition of Minecraft, but because you currently have no other answers, I'll throw in my two cents.

Assuming PE works the same way as the PC version, your world shouldn't be deleted. Structures should spawn in unexplored chunks.

Comment: This is a sheer, unadulterated guess.  If you're going to answer, please at least make an attempt to research the answer, if you haven't played it.

Comment: Well . . . The thing is, there are no sources I have found simply because all of my research on the wiki and other sites do not say anything about this. I did what I could, and if this is of no use, there will still be other posts.

Comment: In the PC edition, structures spawn in new chunks that you haven't explored yet, not unloaded chunks. Unloaded chunks are simply chunks that you have explored but aren't in a 9x9 chunk area around you.

Comment: @angussidney Thanks! Didn't catch that before.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and I would assume they implement things the same way in PE. I guess it works against me then that I've explored a huge area around my base.